# Vector norm Inequality proof

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Does anyone know how to start proving this inequality

$$
\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\| \leq \frac{4 \|x-y\|}{\|x\|+ \|y\|}
$$

The norm is a random norm on a vector space $V$

Comment: If you explain what you've tried so far you'll be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: in fact I tried to subtract the terms in the left hand side, but I couldnt see what to do next !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat complicated proof, I do not know if there is a simpler
and more natural one.

Let $a=||x||,b=||y||,c=||x-y||$. The inequality is easy if $a=b$, so
assume that it is not the case. Since the problem is symmetric in
$x$ and $y$, we can assume $a < b$.

Then $2a < 2b$, so $a+b < 3b-a$, $ \frac{a+b}{3b-a}<1$, and hence
$\frac{b^2-a^2}{3b-a} < b-a$.

The triangle inequality shows that $||y|| \leq ||y-x||+||x||$ ; we deduce
$c \geq  b-a > \frac{b^2-a^2}{3b-a}$. It follows that
$(3b-a)c > b^2-a^2$, $ 4bc > b^2-a^2+(a+b)c$ and hence
$\frac{4c}{a+b} > \frac{b-a+c}{b} $.

So it will suffice to show the following :

$$
\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\| \leq \frac{b-a+c}{b}
\tag{1}
$$

To show (1), we use the identity

$$
\bigg(\frac{x}{a}-\frac{y}{b}\bigg)=
\frac{c}{b}\bigg(\frac{x-y}{c}\bigg)+
\frac{b-a}{b}\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)
 \tag{2}
$$

It follows from (2) that

$$
\bigg(\frac{x}{||x||}-\frac{y}{||y||}\bigg)=
\frac{c}{b}\bigg(\frac{x-y}{||x-y||}\bigg)+
\frac{b-a}{b}\bigg(\frac{x}{||x||}\bigg)
 \tag{3}
$$

Applying the triangle inequality to (3), we see that

$$
 \left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\|
\leq \frac{c}{b}+\frac{b-a}{b} \tag{4}
$$

which concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks .. looks complicated .. especially identity (2) ..

Comment: Complicated, but at least it’s correct and shows your inequality is true.

Comment: exactly .. than you so much again

Comment: @Hiesenberg I rewrote (2) in a simpler form

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier, first assume $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$ which would reduce your inequality to a much more basic
$$
\|x-y\| \leq 2 \|x-y\|
$$
And now to prove the big result, you have it on the unit-scaled versions of the vectors. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks .. Could you explain the next step?

Comment: @Hiesenberg Think about what to do next -- take unit $x$ and non-unit $y$ and think of what would happen?

Comment: Can we then put the terms in the LHS on a common Denominator (norm(y)) and subtract !!

Comment: got stuck again !!

Comment: @gt6989b I'd be interested in some more details too.